# jackson-core: Dependent pair, where type family exists before quantifier in Json data

Tags: java, jackson, dependent-type

I have some incoming JSON (the field-order of which is not my choice) that embeds a dependent pair:

```
{
  "data": {...},
  "evt": "READY",
  ...
}
```

and what type I should read `data` into depends on the value of `evt`. With just a `JsonParser` this is impossible because there's no way to store `data` for later so that it can be returned to once `evt` is reached.

All of the data I'm parsing (unfortunately) already exists in a `ByteBuffer`, so is there a better interface to use than `JsonParser`? I don't want to bring in any more dependencies than `jackson-core` if it can be helped.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is no simple way to achieve this without any additional dependencies.

I suppose, you need to add at least `jackson-databind` (and also `jackson-annotations` if not added automatically via Maven/Gradle).
Then you can use an `ObjectMapper` as an `ObjectCodec` for the parser and parse the complete JSON either into a `TreeNode` structure that can be partically parsed later into the correct type or - if you have objects for all types of data - you maybe can directly parse the complete object with matching data type. If needed, a custom `ObjectCodec` could be implemented to first collect the unknown data and then later process it when the type is known, but implementing an `ObjectCode` does not seem to be that easy.

Instead of Jackson you could use GSON which can either parse the data into the complete object structure or a generic JSON object tree without any additional dependencies.

If you really cannot add additional dependencies, then you could implement a SAX-XML-Parser-like logic using `JsonParser.nextToken`, but I suppose that would require a lot of custom logic.